# python web parser

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I would like to parse a particular database on the web. I would also like to store elements of that database in an online MySQL db.

Why this isn't obvious to me: not sure what language to use, should I be looking at Rails instead of command line python

This is probably the first step in several question, but I suspect you all will provide me insight to links and tutorials

Comment: """you all will provide me insight to links and tutorials""" - unlikely...since this question has been ask a bunch of times and you have not research yourself...search for "python scraping" or "python scrapy" on SO - yes, SO has a search box.

Comment: @Sentinel I know the question was vague and poorly written but I don't think advanced screen scraping tutorials would be good for him. What he needs to tackle are the basics of programming and then a question like this would be phrased better and he would most likely be asking for some good libraries. It sounds like he is unsure of where to even start.

Comment: Sorry but with a reputation of 191 one should be able to write a somewhat reasonable question or *at least* use the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest learning to program and find a language that you are comfortable in. Then after you know some general principals or Ruby, Python or any other language you should be comfortable tackling this on your own. It just seems to me that you are trying to run before you know how to walk so to speak and if you try to jump too far ahead without understanding the basics you can get yourself into a tricky position.

Here are some tutorials to get you started:
  [Chris Pine's - Learn to Program](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/)
  [Zed Shaw's - Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/index)

Comment: thanks for the helpful response! between the other languages I use, sometimes I have to sleep and wake up to new resources at my disposal, instead of hunter gathering them.